# Content not displaying correctly inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Some of my content seems to be pushed below a jQuery plugin I am using called ParticleGround, found here: [ParticleGround GitHub](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground)

I have this code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        $('#Home').particleground({
            dotColor: '#95a5a6',
            lineColor: '#95a5a6'
        });
        }
</script>

    <div class="Home" id="Home">
        <div class="text-vcenter">
            <p class="home">Test</p>
            <p style="color:white; font-family:BebasNeueLight; font-size: 2em;">Cool stuff here</p>
            <p style="color:white;">Info</p>
            <p style="color:white;">Texas, USA</p>
            <br />
            <a class="btn btn-info outline smoothScroll" href="#Services">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Of course all my plugins are properly initialized so that is not the issue.

As you can see in the code above, I have the background as the `#Home` id which is initialized in the `particleground script` to use the effect. Now, this all started happening when I changed this line of code:

```
<div class="centered">
```

to...

```
<div class="text-vcenter">
```

Here is the CSS to:

`#Home`:

```
#Home {
  background: #16a085 no-repeat center center fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

`.centered`:

```
.centered {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

`.text-vcenter`:

```
.text-vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix my content being pushed below the particleground? I'm certain it's an easy fix but I'm coming up blank, it's late at night for me.

**UPDATE:**

It seems to have actually just pushed it down below the 100% view for the particleground and moved it over to the right, where it should be in the center on top of the particleground div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the canvas has a `display: block` on it, so it's pushing the content down. You could set the canvas to be absolutely positioned:

```
canvas{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This way it will be 100% width and height of the `#Home` div, but since it's absolutely positioned, it would be in the background.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4h0ghb67/

Comment: That works fine except now the particleground is showing the moving lines above the text.

Comment: Yeah, I see. In that case you'll need to do like on the demo page. Put the absolute positioning on the `.text-vcenter` div. That's the way it's done [here](http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/)